# How to remove white space above my toolbar Android

Tags: java, android

I am building a simple application. I have white space above my toolbar which I am struggling to remove. Wondering if somebody can help. I have been through many threads to try to get rid of the white space. I have included my code below and attached a picture. Thanks for the help

activity_main:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        tools:openDrawer="start">
    
    
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="bottom"
            >
    
    
            <include
                android:id="@+id/app_bar_main"
                layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
            <include
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                layout="@layout/toolbarlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/menu_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Menu" />
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/add_new_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Add New" />
    
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/home_button"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Home" />
    
        </RelativeLayout>
    
        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#141619"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:itemIconTint="#141619"
            app:itemTextColor="#FFFFFF"
            app:itemTextAppearance="@style/DrawerStyle"
            app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" >
    
        </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
    
    
    
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

toolbarlayout:

```
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#141619"
        />
```

app_bar_main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
        <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
    
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

content_main:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main"
        >
    
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_content_main"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"`enter code here`
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/mobile_navigation" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

manifest

```
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/logo"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/logo_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.mpl">
        android:
        <activity
            android:name=".LoginActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.mpl.NoActionBar"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
    
    </application>
```

themes

```
    <resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <!-- Base application theme. -->
        <style name="Theme.mpl" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
            <!-- Primary brand color. -->
            <item name="colorPrimary">#141619</item>
            <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">#141619</item>
            <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
            <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
            <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
            <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
            <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
            <!-- Status bar color. -->
            <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    
            <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/white</item>
    <!--        <item name="statusBarColor">@color/black</item>-->
    
        </style>
    
        <style name="Theme.mpl.NoActionBar">
            <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">#141619</item>
            <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
            <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
        </style>
    
        <style name="DrawerStyle" parent="android:Widget.TextView">
            <item name="android:textSize">20dp</item>
        </style>
    
        <style name="Theme.mpl.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    
    <!--    <style name="Theme.mpl.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />-->
    </resources>
```

[image]

Comment: What theme are you using on your manifest? Probably the white space is an action bar.

Comment: I have added my manifest and theme

Comment: <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> Has to be in Theme.mpl since you are using your own toolbars

Comment: I have added <item name="windowActionBar">false</item> to theme.xml and it doesnt get rid of it

Comment: @pilotman I am not able to view image which you posted.

Comment: @VatsalDholakiya I have re-added the picture

Comment: I have fixed this by adding the theme to the <activity android:name=".MainActivity" />
Thanls for all your help much appreciated